# sum of Times in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have some records like this:

```
ID       Personel_Code        Time 
---      -------------       ------ 
1         0011                05:50
3         0011                20:12
4         0012                00:50
```

I want to have the sum of times for each person. in this example I want to have the result like this :

```
Personel_Code          Time
-------------          -----
 0011                  26:02
 0012                   00:50
```

Thank you.

Comment: Really depends on your DB server... Which is it? And depends how to you save time fields, as strings or you use date/time data types.

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm using sql-server 2005. TIME is stored as string. can't I cast it to time? unfortunately I'm not good in writing query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you'd do something like this in SQL Server (just a hint, you have to work on details and conversions)

```
SELECT Personel_Code, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', convert(time, Time, 8))) as totalTime
FROM thisTable
GROUP BY Personel_Code
```